# Calling performFetch in viewWillAppear doesn't work

Tags: ios, core-data

The first call inside `viewWillAppear` doesn't work. The second call in block callback works. It doesn't hurt anything, but I wonder why?

In my understanding, calling `performFetch` should be a one-time thing provided that no changes made to NSFRC afterwards. Since I am lazy loading the `frc`, it's not possible that it gets modified in any way. After calling `performFetch` and `reloadData`, NSFRC will start monitoring the context. And any changes in context will be populated to table view automatically.

Yet in my code, if I remove `reloadData` following the second `performFetch`, nothing happens to the table view. Base on that I think the first `performFetch` totally doesn't take effect.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)frc
{
    if (!_frc) {
        [_frc setDelegate:self];
        NSFetchRequest *freq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        [freq setSortDescriptors:@[sd]];

        _frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:freq managedObjectContext:[[BNRStore sharedStore]context] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    }
    return _frc;
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // first time
    NSError *storeError = nil;
    if (![self.frc performFetch:&storeError]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[storeError localizedDescription]);}
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    if ( [[self.frc fetchedObjects] count] == 0) {
        [[BNRStore sharedStore] fetch:^(NSError *error){
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av show];
            } else {

                // second time
                NSError *storeError = nil;
                if (![self.frc performFetch:&storeError]) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[storeError localizedDescription]);}
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting yourself as the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate before you initialized it. You can send messages to `nil` (which it still is at that point), so you don't get any errors. However, your delegate is never set anywhere else, so your table view doesn't get updated either. Move the call to `setDelegate` to after the initialization and it should work:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)frc
{
    if (!_frc) {
        NSFetchRequest *freq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        [freq setSortDescriptors:@[sd]];

        _frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:freq managedObjectContext:[[BNRStore sharedStore]context] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        [_frc setDelegate:self];
    }
    return _frc;
}
```